# Check whether already my app is running using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Is any way to find whether my Phonegap app running in background using javascript or the Cordova plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Just have it write to the console on a timed basis & then run it in the debugger while USB attached to your PC or Mac. If it's running in the background, you'll see your messages on the console. If not... not. Something like:

```
// Write a message to the console every 15 seconds
var myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Number 5 is alive!");
}, 15000);
```

Comment: Here is the plugin i find useful [corodova background](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)